# Skip a loop iteration with Firebird 2.5

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I need to skip a `While...Do` loop iteration inside a stored procedure like this

```
While (v_counter <= :v_total) do begin

  If (<condition>) then continue;

  ...

end
```

However `CONTINUE` won't be available until Firebird 3.0. Is there a work a round for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to skip an iteration through a loop without `CONTINUE`, then just use the inverse of the continue-condition for the rest of the block:

```
While (v_counter <= :v_total) do begin

  If (NOT <condition>) then
  BEGIN
     ...
  END

end
```